# MySQL order by COUNT DISTINCT

Tags: mysql, count, distinct

```
2.8.7
2.8.3
2.8.2
2.8.7
2.8.5
2.8.7
2.8.7
2.8.5
2.6.0
2.8.3
2.6.4
2.6.3
2.8.4
2.8.0
2.6.3
2.8.5
2.8.5
2.8.5
2.6.0
2.8.2
```

How do I bring a unique value version sorted by the number of these versions?

At the exit I want to get the following:

2.8.5     5

2.8.7     4

2.6.0     2

2.6.3     2

2.8.2     2

2.8.3     2

2.8.4     2

2.6.4     1

2.8.0     1

ORDER BY count unique versions))

Sorry for my bad english

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
SELECT
  version,
  COUNT(*) AS num
FROM
  my_table
GROUP BY
  version
ORDER BY
  COUNT(*) DESC
```

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT version, COUNT(*) FROM tablename
GROUP BY version
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC;
```

or, alternate syntax

```
SELECT version, COUNT(*) FROM tablename
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 2 DESC;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select version, count(*) from sometable group by version order by count(*) desc;
```